# Using custom file formats as Windows Explorer file systems

Tags: winapi, filesystems, windows-explorer

Are there any tutorials on how to load custom archive file formats as file systems in Windows Explorer, similar to CAB and ZIP files?

I tried searching for namespace extensions tutorials, but it appears to be a different thing.

Comment: They're practically the same. The only difference is that a namespace extension register its own folder onto a specific namespace. i.e.: *Control Panel* is registered onto *My Computer* namespace. For file based folder, the namespace extension is *attached* to its file type. See "*Implementing the Basic Folder Object Interfaces*" in MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See this project - Mini Shell Extension Framework.**

1. [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8063/The-Mini-Shell-Extension-Framework-Part-I)
2. [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9421/The-Mini-Shell-extension-Framework-Part-II)
3. [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11674/The-Mini-Shell-Extension-Framework-Part-III)

Most important for you is first part, from project description:

> In order to show how to use the classes and to provide a sample of how
>   to create a shell extension, the code includes a small sample that can
>   open .vvv files. VVV files are just renamed .ini files that act as a
>   container. Most shell extensions are container views (for example, the
>   Windows .zip and .cab shell extensions).